# PHP. Перестановка элементов массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив `$X = [0,-5,-9,3,76,-99,-3,-4,101,-212,10,31];`
Надо переставить отрицательные элементы из в начало массива, а положительные в конец, сохранив при этом их очередность, то есть :[-5,-9,-99,-3,-4,-212,0,3,76,101,10,31].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$x = [0,-5,-9,3,76,-99,-3,-4,101,-212,10,31];
foreach ($x as $k => $i) {
    if ($i < 0) {
        $y[] = $i;
        unset($x[$k]);
    }
}
print_r(array_merge($y, $x));


$x = [0,-5,-9,3,76,-99,-3,-4,101,-212,10,31];
foreach ($x as $k => $i) {
    if ($i >= 0) {
        array_push($x, $x[$k]);
        unset($x[$k]);
    }
}
print_r($x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [`usort`](https://php.net/usort).

```php
usort($x, function(int $a, int $b){
    if($a < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    if($b < 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: слова "сохранив очередность" вы как то мимо пропустили?

Comment: Отнюдь. Вам сначала следовало бы проверить решение, прежде чем писать комментарий - https://3v4l.org/kt22f .

Comment: да, пардоньте, показалось, чтоб обычная сортировка. ловите плюс

Comment: интересно вот кстати, возможно ли, что он таки переставит местами два положительных, или нет.

Comment: Нет, `return 0;` (для положительных чисел) обозначает, что нужно оставить тот порядок, который есть.

Comment: не правда, `0` обозначает что числа равны. а вот порядок следования не гарантирован, это оговорено в документации. Понятное дело что в рамках одной версии пхп результат будет одинаков, но потенциально при смене версии, он может изменится. а вот случались ли такие изменения когда-либо я не в курсе.

Answer (score 1):

заведите два массива, один для отрицательных другой для положительных. Пройдитесь циклом по данному и распихайте значения в эти два. а затем слейте в один в нужном порядке. что-то вроде такого

```
$p = []; $n = [];
foreach($values as $v){
   $v >= 0 ? $p[] = $v: $n[] = $v;
}
$result  = array_merge($n, $p);
```